# Calculating expected value of a JPDF?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be discrete random variables with joint probability density function $P(x,y) = 2^{x-y+1}$ when $x= 1,2$ and $y= 1,2$ and $0$ otherwise.

How do I find $E[x/y]$?

Comment: Your $P(x,y)$ is neither a probability density function, nor a probability mass function. Did you copy the problem correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my calculations are right, this is what you should get:
$E[\frac{x}{y}]=\sum\limits_{x\in{1,2}}\sum\limits_{y\in{1,2}}\frac{x}{y}2^{x-y+1}= \frac{1}{2}2^{1-2+1}+\frac{1}{1}2^{1-1+1}+\frac{2}{2}2^{2-2+1}\frac{2}{1}2^{2-1+1}=12.5$